# System.StackOverflowException Occuring with LinqToHtml

Tags: .net, vb.net, stack-overflow

I have inherited a web spider application, with all source code.    It appears that for normal brochure style websites (say under 15 pages), the software runs perfectly fine.

For others, (over 20ish pages), the software throws the StackOverflowException on the line marked in the code below.

It does not appear to be utilitzing recursion, and unfortunately, there is no support for the LinqToHtml (SuperStarCoders) library being used.

Here is the code that is running when the exception occurs:

```
   Private Function ExportXml(Optional ByVal _Worker As ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = Nothing) As Boolean
    Dim _L = PopulateSEOList(_Worker)
    Try
        Dim _TmpStr As New Text.StringBuilder
        Dim _X As New XDocument, _ct As Long = 0, _Elements As Typing.SEO.Elements = Nothing
        ReportProgress(0, _Worker)
        With _TmpStr
            .Append("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>")
            .Append("<o7th.Web.Design.Web.Spider>")
            For i As Long = 0 To _L.Count - 1
                _ct += 1
                .Append("   <Page>")
                .Append("       <Link>" & XmlEscape(_L(i).Link) & "</Link>")
                .Append("       <Title>" & XmlEscape(_L(i).Title) & "</Title>")
                .Append("       <Keywords>" & XmlEscape(_L(i).Keywords) & "</Keywords>")
                .Append("       <Description>" & XmlEscape(_L(i).Description) & "</Description>")
                .Append("       <Elements>")
                _Elements = _L(i).ContentElements
                If _Elements IsNot Nothing Then
                    If _Elements.H1 IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<H1>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.H1.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= XmlEscape(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </H1>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.H2 IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<H2>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.H2.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= XmlEscape(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </H2>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.H3 IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<H3>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.H3.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= XmlEscape(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </H3>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.H4 IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<H4>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.H4.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= XmlEscape(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </H4>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.H5 IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<H5>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.H5.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= XmlEscape(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </H5>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.H6 IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<H6>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.H6.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= XmlEscape(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </H6>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.UL IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<UL>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.UL.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= ConvertToCDATA(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </UL>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.OL IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<OL>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.OL.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= ConvertToCDATA(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </OL>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.STRONG IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<STRONG>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.STRONG.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= XmlEscape(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </STRONG>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.EM IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<EM>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.EM.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= XmlEscape(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </EM>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.BLOCKQUOTE IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<BLOCKQUOTE>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.BLOCKQUOTE.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content><%= ConvertToCDATA(n) %></Content>).ToList() %>
                                </BLOCKQUOTE>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.A IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<LINKS>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.A.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content>
                                            <HREF><%= XmlEscape(n.Href) %></HREF>
                                            <REL><%= XmlEscape(n.Rel) %></REL>
                                            <TITLE><%= XmlEscape(n.Title) %></TITLE>
                                            <TARGET><%= XmlEscape(n.Target) %></TARGET>
                                            <CONTENT><%= XmlEscape(n.Content) %></CONTENT>
                                        </Content>).ToList() %>
                                </LINKS>)
                    End If
                    If _Elements.IMG IsNot Nothing Then
                        .Append(<IMAGES>
                                    <%= (From n In _Elements.IMG.AsParallel()
                                        Select
                                        <Content>
                                            <SRC><%= XmlEscape(n.Source) %></SRC>
                                            <ALT><%= XmlEscape(n.Alt) %></ALT>
                                            <TITLE><%= XmlEscape(n.Title) %></TITLE>
                                        </Content>).ToList() %>
                                </IMAGES>)
                    End If
                End If
                .Append("       </Elements>")
                .Append("       <Content><![CDATA[" & _L(i).Content.ToString() & "]]></Content>")
                .Append("   </Page>")
                ReportProgress((_ct / _L.Count) * 100, _Worker)
            Next
            .Append("</o7th.Web.Design.Web.Spider>")
        End With
        Dim _xStr As String = _TmpStr.ToString()
        _X = XDocument.Parse(_xStr)
        _X.Save(ExportPath & "site.xml")
        _X = Nothing
        ReportProgress(100, _Worker)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Put logging in here
        Message = ex.Message & ":::Export.ExportXml"
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The LinkList variable above is a list(of Typing.Links):

```
Partial Public Class Links
    Public Property SiteUrl As String
    Public Property SiteTitle As String
    Public Property Site As String
End Class
```

The other 2 lists are:

```
Imports Superstar.Html.Linq

Public Class Typing

Partial Public Class SEO

    Public Property Link As String
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Keywords As String
    Public Property Content As HElement
    Public Property ContentElements As Elements

    Partial Public Class Elements

        Public Property H1 As List(Of String)
        Public Property H2 As List(Of String)
        Public Property H3 As List(Of String)
        Public Property H4 As List(Of String)
        Public Property H5 As List(Of String)
        Public Property H6 As List(Of String)
        Public Property UL As List(Of String)
        Public Property OL As List(Of String)
        Public Property STRONG As List(Of String)
        Public Property BLOCKQUOTE As List(Of String)
        Public Property EM As List(Of String)
        Public Property A As List(Of Links)
        Public Property IMG As List(Of Images)

        Partial Public Class Images
            Public Property Source As String
            Public Property Alt As String
            Public Property Title As String
        End Class

        Partial Public Class Links
            Public Property Href As String
            Public Property Rel As String
            Public Property Title As String
            Public Property Target As String
            Public Property Content As String
        End Class

    End Class

End Class

End Class
```

ReportProgress simply reports and updates the backgroundworker of the Xaml window for this particual circumstance to update a progress bar:

```
Public Sub ReportProgress(ByVal ct As Integer, _Worker As ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
    If _Worker IsNot Nothing Then
        _Worker.ReportProgress(ct)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    End If
End Sub
```

, and the Downloader class is:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Net
Imports Superstar.Html.Linq

Public Class Downloader
Implements IDisposable

''' <summary>
''' Get the returned downloaded string
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property ReturnString As String
    Get
        Return _StrReturn
    End Get
End Property
Private Property _StrReturn As String

''' <summary>
''' Get the returned downloaded byte array
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property ReturnBytes As Byte()
    Get
        Return _FSReturn
    End Get
End Property
Private Property _FSReturn As Byte()

Private Property _UserAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"
Private Property DataReceived As Boolean = False

''' <summary>
''' Download a string, but do not block the calling thread
''' </summary>
''' <param name="_Path"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub DownloadString(ByVal _Path As String, Optional ByVal _Worker As ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = Nothing)
    SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
    Using wc As New Net.WebClient()
        With wc
            Dim _ct As Long = 0
            DataReceived = False
            .Headers.Add("user-agent", _UserAgent)
            .DownloadStringAsync(New System.Uri(_Path))
            AddHandler .DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf StringDownloaded
            Do While Not DataReceived
                If _Worker IsNot Nothing Then
                    _ct += 1
                    ReportProgress(_ct, _Worker)
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    End Using
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Download a file, but do not block the calling thread
''' </summary>
''' <param name="_Path"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _Path As String, Optional ByVal _Worker As ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = Nothing)
    SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
    Using wc As New Net.WebClient()
        With wc
            Dim _ct As Long = 0
            DataReceived = False
            .Headers.Add("user-agent", _UserAgent)
            .DownloadDataAsync(New System.Uri(_Path))
            AddHandler .DownloadDataCompleted, AddressOf FileStreamDownload
            Do While Not DataReceived
                If _Worker IsNot Nothing Then
                    _ct += 1
                    ReportProgress(_ct, _Worker)
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    End Using
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Download a parsable HDocument, for using HtmlToLinq
''' </summary>
''' <param name="_Path"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function DownloadHDoc(ByVal _Path As String, Optional ByVal _Worker As ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = Nothing) As HDocument
    Try
        'StackOverFlowException Occurring Here!
        DownloadString(_Path, _Worker)
        Return HDocument.Parse(_StrReturn)
    Catch soex As StackOverflowException
        'put some logging in here, with the path attempted
        Return Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
        Return HDocument.Load(_Path)
    End Try
End Function

#Region "Internals"

Private Sub SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
    Dim a As New System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection
    Dim aNetAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(a.GetType)
    Dim aSettingsType As Type = aNetAssembly.GetType("System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal")
    Dim args As Object() = Nothing
    Dim anInstance As Object = aSettingsType.InvokeMember("Section", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.GetProperty Or BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing, Nothing, args)
    Dim aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing As FieldInfo = aSettingsType.GetField("useUnsafeHeaderParsing", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing.SetValue(anInstance, True)
End Sub

Private Sub FileStreamDownload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then
        DataReceived = True
        _FSReturn = DirectCast(e.Result, Byte())
    Else
        _FSReturn = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub StringDownloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then
        DataReceived = True
        _StrReturn = DirectCast(e.Result, String)
    Else
        _StrReturn = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub

#End Region

#Region "IDisposable Support"
Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

' IDisposable
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
        End If
        _StrReturn = Nothing
        _FSReturn = Nothing
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
End Sub

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

As I said above, it does not look like there is any recursion happenning.  (at least none that truly stick out at me), so I immediatly assume that it is within the HDocument.Parse that it is happenning.

Can you tell me where this is wrong, and how to correct the issue?

I have done some research, and understand that the default stack size is only 1MB, so I wonder if this is truly one of those special circumstances where I should attempt to increase this...

I found after watching the trace a number of times, that it always occurred when it hit a particular page. This page, just so happens to be over 500k in size.

Here is the Call Stack:

```
[External Code] 
>       o7th.Web.Design.Spider.Worker.dll!o7th.Web.Design.Spider.Worker.Downloader.DownloadHDoc(String _Path, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker _Worker) Line 95 + 0x1e bytes  Basic
o7th.Web.Design.Spider.Worker.dll!o7th.Web.Design.Spider.Worker.Export.PopulateSEOList(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker _Worker) Line 513 + 0x65 bytes    Basic
o7th.Web.Design.Spider.Worker.dll!o7th.Web.Design.Spider.Worker.Export.ExportXml(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker _Worker) Line 70 + 0x1e bytes   Basic
o7th.Web.Design.Spider.Worker.dll!o7th.Web.Design.Spider.Worker.Export.RunExport(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker _Worker) Line 30 + 0x17 bytes   Basic
o7th.Web.Design.WebSpider.exe!o7th.Web.Design.WebSpider.ParseLinks.RunExport(Object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e) Line 106 + 0x2c bytes  Basic
[External Code]
```

And Locals shows me the page I mention above that is over 500k in size

Comment: p.s.   you can probably see the attempts in here at possibly cleaning up the initial list (figuring that was part of the problem)

Comment: another note.   It's not the number of pages that is doing it.   I found after watching the trace a number of times, that it always occurred when it hit a particular page.   This page, just so happens to be over 500k in size.

Comment: I think the code is flawed anyway. Besides using way too much parallelism (imho), several tasks/threads iterate through _doc.Descendants which is not (most likely) threadsafe. And in such cases a StackOverflow MIGHT be the result?

Comment: Can you break on this exception, capture a call stack and post it here?

Comment: @sll - that won't necessarily help as the stack will only show the last few calls. A better approach would be to step into `DownloadHDoc` and then `DownloadString` to see why it calls itself.

Comment: I removed the parellism, thinking it might be the cause, however the exception still happens.  Please see my question, as I editted it and found where, and on what page this is happenning on.    Once, I get rid of said page from the list to parse, the exception does not occur

Comment: @ChrisF p.s.  Neither `DownloadHDoc` nor `DownloadString` call themselves.  Please see the code in the question

Comment: @Kevin - I didn't mean to imply that they were calling each other directly, but indirectly.

Comment: Could it be the "Do while not ready" loop (in DownloadString)? You are pushing messages into the queue at a very high rate. See Chris Haas post, I guess that could be the right suggestion. Why not simply use a waithandle instead of the loop and set it into the completed event?

Comment: i've sincec removed the `do-while` loop, as it is unnecessary to begin with.  I would not use a waithandle, the whole purpose is to not lock up the gui, and using a waithandle will lock the gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I needed more space otherwise I would have added this as a comment to @Jakub Konecki's post.)

I've built several spiders over the years and the only big performance gain for parallelism is the actual downloading of URLs. You might shave a couple of hundred milliseconds of HTML parsing on large documents but the gain isn't worth the debugging price. So make your life easier and remove the parallelism.

You've also got a weird async blocking problem. In `DownloadHDoc` you're calling `DownloadString` synchronously but then inside of `DownloadString` you're kicking off an async method and then blocking on a bit flag thus defeating the purpose of the async. What's worse is that you're blocking in a `do-while` loop which is spinning at a million miles per hour and calling `ReportProgress` every time. I expect this is what's actually giving you the SOE. Putting a `Thread.Sleep(100)` in there might help you for starters.

**[EDIT]**

The code that is blocking on the bit flag is this:

```
        .DownloadStringAsync(New System.Uri(_Path))
        AddHandler .DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf StringDownloaded
        Do While Not DataReceived
            If _Worker IsNot Nothing Then
                _ct += 1
                ReportProgress(_ct, _Worker)
            End If
        Loop
```

Line 1 kicks off an async method, line 2 adds a handler for the completion and returns immediately. Line 3 is checking a global variable over and over and over waiting for the function `StringDownloaded` to set it. This is happening hundreds or thousands (or more) of times every second. Although not optimal, what makes it bad is that you are calling `ReportProgress` method every time. The larger the document the more calls to `ReportProgress` will be made. You really only need to update the UI every 100ms at most, I usually set mine to every 250ms or 500ms.

**[EDIT 2]**

If the above was the problem you should be able to change it to something like:

```
    .DownloadStringAsync(New System.Uri(_Path))
    AddHandler .DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf StringDownloaded
    Do While Not DataReceived
        If _Worker IsNot Nothing Then
            _ct += 1
            ReportProgress(_ct, _Worker)
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(250) ''//Sleep inside of the loop
    Loop
```

Comment: please read all comments above, you'll see I did remove the parallelism :)    Also, please explain a little about the _blocking on a bit flag_ as I am unsure where you mean.  Also `ReportProgress` initially had that exact Sleep value, initially.  I had removed it because I thought it may be unnecessary.  I will add it back in and try it out though, and see what happens

Comment: tried adding back in the `Thread.Sleep(100)` and played a bit with the number, but same SOE, same Call Stack, same Locals

Comment: so I wonder.  Would adding in the `Thread.Sleep(100)` above the `do-while` loop make this any better...

Comment: Hi Kevin, I don't mean to be a pain but can you post your updated code? Its hard to read 300+ lines of code and then guess at the edits that were made.

Comment: Try commenting out `ReportProgress(_ct, _Worker)` for starters.

Comment: nope.  makes no difference.  Still SOE once that one page is hit.  If i remove that page, it works just fine.  In fact, I also tested it on a site with over 1k pages, and it worked fine on that as well.  (all pages were under 20k in size)    this one that I am testing, is 190+ pages, all but one are under 200k, the one that this fails on is over 500k, which has me thinking that HDocument simply cannot handle documents that big

Comment: posted update code, will try commenting out `ReportProgress` now

Comment: That worked!  Like a tool, I had it tied to the download processes, as well as the `PopulateSEOList` method.    It still happens with wierd circumstances, but no longer happens with with just pages.  (this site for some reason populates my initial 'page' list with a couple images that are linked to from the home page, and inside the site root folder).  I have a few more _tests_ to run, but it looks like that was it

Comment: `[Edit 2]` not even needed.   `PopulateSEOList` already had the `ReportProgress` =)

Comment: thank you for the help.  Now that it's working, time to clean up!   =D

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing all the parallelism - it's probably to excessive anyway and the overhead of creating multiple threads is bigger than the performance gain.

Once you do that, just debug the code and wait for the exception. You can than check the call stack and all the collections.

Stack overflow usually happens when you recursively call the same method and the end condition doesn't kick in for some reason. You will see it clearly in the call stack.

Comment: I did, and the result was the same.   Please see my question, as I editted it and found where, and on what page this is happenning on.    Once, I get rid of said page from the list to parse, the exception does not occur

Comment: will post in a minute...  running another test currently

Comment: too big to post here, i'll post it in the question